# Inventory-Tool needed for HW and SW

Tags: inventory-software

I'm searching for a SW and HW inventory-tool for a small business. I found a lot of fancy and expensive tools on the net, but nothing which is useful for us.

I don't need something which can "scan the network". I need a cheap (or better free) tool, in which I can manage our hardware and software.

Hardware:

- Buy date
- warranty type and date
- serial number
- product number
- manufacturer
- model
- vendor
- user
- item number
- notes
- (maybe some hw-details like RAM and CPU)

Software:

- item number
- title
- version
- manufacturer
- serial number
- license type and quantity
- user(s)
- notes

some suggestions / ideas? or questions regarding my needs?

Comment: For figuring out what you have in your computer, I find Speccy to be quite nice (and free), but not a tool for collecting data about many machines I guess. http://www.piriform.com/speccy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [**Spiceworks**](http://www.spiceworks.com/).  It's free.

[image: Spiceworks]

Comment: I've been using Spiceworks since version 3 and it's awesome. I keep track of all my inventory like that.

Comment: Spiceworks looks good, but is an overkill for what I want to do. We now wrote our own little tool for that.